# What exactly is the OpenCR part?

Tags: ros, opencr

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure what it is. It looks like it might be an Arduino-compatible control board that is somehow especially well suited for ROS. But OTOH I see configurations that combine a Pi with an OpenCR so that confuses me. I've seen this: OpenCR3 and this: OpenCR5 but I am still not sure...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263511/what-exactly-is-the-opencr-part?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2017-06-08

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi :)

Thank you for your interest in OpenCR.
This is why OpenCR especially well suited for ROS.

First, it has quite powerful main chip(ARM Cortex-M7 with floating point unit) and many digital and analog input/out pins(UART, SPI, I2C). It helps control and operating robot with various sensor data in precise period.

Second, it support power outputs(3.3v, 5v, 12v). Users can use this power for their robots or sensors and it helps operating single board computer.

Third, it can publish or subscribe topic using [ROS Serial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial) . This main function helps ROS users want to use ROS library to their robots handily.

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2017-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2017-06-08**:
Thanks! I admit being a newbie here and just feeling my way. So typically is OpenCR combined with another processor (Pi, Arduino, NUC)? In other words if my robot is meant to carry all the processing onboard, would a good config be to combine an OpenCR with another more powerful processor, or if I h

**Comment by [cheristi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30700/cheristi/) on 2017-06-09**:
What is the expected price for the OpenCR?

Are there already alternatives available? I'm looking for something that drives dc motors, stepper motors and has inputs for 7.2V Lipo (which it should convert to 5V to drive the raspberry pi).

**Comment by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) on 2017-06-11**:
@pitosalas OpenCR can be connected to Pi, NUC that has USB port. For example, OpenCR is used control your robot and sense adjacent environment, while other computer(Pi, NUC, Laptop...) has more powerful processor calculates complex algorithm using given data from OpenCR.

**Comment by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) on 2017-06-11**:
@cheristi About price information reference please contact to contactus2@robotis.com. Thanks.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2017-06-11**:
Can you point me to a code sample that shows how the OpenCR and the Pi divide up the work? I guess I don't understand, if I have a pi on board, why would I also need the openCr?

**Comment by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) on 2017-06-12**:
@pitosalas SBC(Pi) and MCU board(OpenCR) has some differences. The MCU board is small and has real-time computing with low power(3.3v, 5v). SBC has operating system. These two electronic devices can cover each other's disadvantages(real-time and computing power). So we use both for robot.

**Comment by [wintermute](https://answers.ros.org/users/26115/wintermute/) on 2017-09-07**:
Hello,
Where exactly can we buy one? Is it the same as OpenCM: http://en.robotis.com/index/product.php?cate_code=131010